# Verifying Certificate using Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, ssl, certificate

In Mac Terminal, we can use the command `security` to do many things related to certificates. I'm trying to know how to verify a certificate using this command. I wrote `security verify-cert [.pem path]> output.txt` but it didn't show any details! How can I show a certificate detail using this command?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> verify-cert [-c certFile] [-r rootCertFile] [-p policy] [-k keychain] [-n] [-L] [-l] [-e
>      emailAddress] [-s sslHost] [-q]
>             Verify one or more certificates.

```
      Options:
      -c certFile     Certificate to verify, in DER or PEM format. Can be specified
                      more than once; leaf certificate has to be specified first.
```

Try this instead:
`security verify-cert -c certificate.pem`

Comment: Thank you Ram! This just writes (...certificate verification successful) without showing details. I looked at the documentation and I didn't find any property that show the certificate details (the issuer, public key, and so on). Can you tell how to do so?

Comment: verify-cert is used to verify a cert not display details. I think this answers your question "I'm trying to know how to verify a certificate using this command". If you mark this question as answered and ask another I will be happy to answer that one too the same way (reading the documentation for the OSC security command...). Cheers.